# phpmyadmin session ID visible in url

Tags: security, session, phpmyadmin, session-variables

The session ID is visible in the browser bar when I use PHPMyAdmin. I know it's not an issue if is correctly sanitized and session_regenerate_id is used when you log in, but... it was highlighted in an audit and I was just wondering if there's any easy way to suppress it? I haven't found anything in the documentation.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean `token` URL parameter in phpMyAdmin by session ID. It have a unique 32 digit hexadecimal value each time like `5aa05b6c88681722a043c244b693950d`. It is used by phpMyAdmin to prevent `CSRF - Cross site request forgery`. See [phpMyAdmin documentation](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Security_Of_phpMyAdmin) and [Cross site request forgery](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) for more information about this.

It is part of phpMyAdmin core and I don't think there is any easy workaround to disable this except hacking the phpMyAdmin source code to remove this feature.